# Alive or dead: me, both ways, you need. What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Fore! You yell, as a ball flies through the sky.
>
> Me, you will yell, or somebody could die.
>
> Everyday, in some way you see me,
>
> Learning to see the forest for the trees.
>
> It can’t be avoided, I’m useful indeed.
>
> Alive or dead: me, both ways, you need.

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are:

> TIMBER!!!
>
>  (In English, lumberjacks or tree-fellers shout "Timber!" when a tree is about to fall. I believe in other languages the word they shout translates as "wood!" or "tree!")

Fore! You yell, as a ball flies through the sky.
Me, you will yell, or somebody could die.

> "Fore!" is shouted to warn people during a game of golf.
>  Likewise "Timber!" is shouted when a tree is felled so it doesn't land on their heads and kill them.

Everyday, in some way you see me

> Wood, or timber is everywhere, used as a building material, in packaging etc etc.

Learning to see the forest for the trees.

> Timber or wood comes from trees. "Cannot see the forest for the trees" is a well-known saying, as is the similar "cannot see the *wood* for the trees" (although in this sense "wood" refers to a small collection of trees).

It can’t be avoided, I’m useful indeed.

> Wood is very useful, for building, or as fuel. And you can't go far without encountering something made of wood.

Alive or dead: me, both ways, you need.

> We need living trees to provide oxygen, but we make useful things from dead wood.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be

> **Help**?

`Fore! You yell, as a ball flies through the sky.`

> You only say this to prevent any injuries in case a **golf ball** hits someone (more accurate info can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fore_(golf)), including the origin of the term). This call demonstrates an act of **helping** someone by lessening the **potential** of the golf ball striking them.

`Me, you will yell, or somebody could die.`

> If you suddenly find someone in a state of near **death**, you would surely yell *Help!* wouldn't you?

`Everyday, in some way, you see me,`

> Everyday you see an act of **help**; for example, bees help the **survival** of plants by collecting their pollen and doing some other fancy works. Every animal species **contributes** to an ecosystem in one way or another.

`Learning to see the forest for the trees.`

> [Deforestation](https://www.livescience.com/27692-deforestation.html) is a terrible thing (ever watched the movie, [The Lorax](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1482459/)?) and with some **help**, we are trying to save animals that are losing their habitats via this crime.

`It can't be avoided, I'm useful indeed.`

> Our **brains** help us to do all sorts of things, so help can't really be avoided, and is thus very useful.

`Alive or dead: me, both ways, you need.`

> Not too sure. We are all dying, quicker and slower than others. We need help?

---

`What am I?`

> **Help**?

$$\stackrel{\bullet\,\bullet}{\smile}$$